# newsletter3k, find author name in visible text after first "by" word

Tags: beautifulsoup, extract, cpu-word, visible, newspaper3k

Newsletter3K is a good python Library for News content extraction. It works **mostly** well
.I want to extract names after first "by" word in visible text. This is my code, it did not work well, somebody out there please help:

```
import re
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import ArticleException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0)Gecko/20100101   Firefox/78.0'
config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10 
html1='https://saugeentimes.com/new-perspectives-a-senior-moment-food-glorious-food-part-2/'
article = Article(html1.strip(), config=config)
article.download()
article.parse()
soup = BeautifulSoup(article)
## I want to take only visible text
[s.extract() for s in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
visible_text = soup.getText()
for line in visible_text:
    # Capture one-or-more words after first (By or by) the initial match
    match = re.search(r'By (\S+)', line)

    # Did we find a match?
    if match:
        # Yes, process it to print 
        By = match.group(1)
        print('By {}'.format(By))`
```

Comment: Are you trying to get this code to work only for *saugeentimes.com* or do you plan on querying multiple sources with the same code?

Comment: Yes, I want to query multiple sources similar to  saugeentimes.com.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Please provide additional sources in your question.

Comment: In following webpages, author names appear after the first visible "by" word:    1. http://thenelsondaily.com/regionalnews?amp%3Bquicktabs_1=2&quicktabs_1=1%22%27&qt-qt_nelson_regional_international=1&page=5      2. http://thenelsondaily.com/regionalnews?amp%3Bquicktabs_1=2&quicktabs_1=1%22%27&qt-qt_nelson_regional_international=1&page=7
       3. https://www.macleans.ca/education/what-college-students-in-canada-can-expect-during-covid/    4. https://www.cnn.com/2020/10/09/business/edinburgh-woollen-mill-job-cuts/index.html

Comment: The Author name (in some web articles), comes between title and date

Comment: I would recommend reviewing my [newspaper overview document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview), because some of the sites that you provided can be easily queried using code from that document.  Some of the other sites will likely require a different approach.  Most likely requests, BS4 and regex.  Please rework your question for the sites that cannot be extracted using my overview examples.

Comment: I will explore your newspaper overview document again. It would be great if you teach other approaches " Some of the other sites will likely require a different approach" @Life is complex

Comment: I spent the time developing an answer that can handle several "author name" use cases from the URLs that you provided.  The answer can be expanded to fit additional use cases as needed.  Please accept this answer, because it has all the details that you requested in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a comprehensive answer, but it is one that you can build from.  You will need to expand this code as you add additional sources.  Like I stated before my [Newspaper3k overview document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) has lots of extraction examples, so please review it thoroughly.

Regular expressions should be a last ditch effort after trying these extraction methods with *newspaper3k*:

- article.authors
- meta tags
- json
- soup

```
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper.utils import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10

urls = ['https://saugeentimes.com/new-perspectives-a-senior-moment-food-glorious-food-part-2',
        'https://www.macleans.ca/education/what-college-students-in-canada-can-expect-during-covid',
        'https://www.cnn.com/2021/02/12/asia/india-glacier-raini-village-chipko-intl-hnk/index.html',
        'https://www.latimes.com/california/story/2021-02-13/wildfire-santa-cruz-boulder-creek-residents-fear-water'
        '-quality',
        'https://foxbaltimore.com/news/local/maryland-lawmakers-move-ahead-with-first-tax-on-internet-ads-02-13-2021']

for url in urls:
    try:
        article = Article(url, config=config)
        article.download()
        article.parse()
        author = article.authors
        if author:
            print(author)
        elif not author:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(article.html, 'html.parser')
            author_tag = soup.find(True, {'class': ['td-post-author-name', 'byline']}).find(['a', 'span'])
            if author_tag:
                print(author_tag.get_text().replace('By', '').strip())
            else:
                print('no author found')
    except AttributeError as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Now, I have doubts about using newsletter3k as a complete solution for web article scraping: title, URL, authors, images, text, publication date, and summary.  Is there any other tool to try, which is better than newspaper3k, dear experts?

Comment: newsletter3k isn't perfect, but it's a decent python module.  I have learned the module's parameters and know that I need to look at the source of a target website to determine what harvest methods will work.  You have to do the same thing when using beautiful soup, selenium or scrapy.  My newsletter3k  overview document was written to inform others on the usages of the module against specific sites.  That document provides anyone with the base knowledge on how to wield the library with efficiency.

Comment: Thank you, I took it as NO answer. So still Newspaper is a choice.

Comment: Not a no, but a maybe with limitations.

Comment: I mean, Newsletter is still a thing to go.

Comment: Yes, newspaper is still a thing to use when harvesting specific content.

Comment: obsessed to find by pls help:s = requests_html.HTMLSession()
page = s.get('http://oshawaexpress.ca/oshawa-student-receives-70000-scholarship/')
soup=bs(page.text,'lxml')
teks=soup.get_text()
teks = "\n".join([ll.rstrip() for ll in teks.splitlines() if ll.strip()])
## 4,
# for line in teks:
#     m = re.search(r'(by\=.+?(?= )|by\=.+?$)', line)
#     if m:
#         text = m.group() # Matched text here
#         print (text)    
## 3, below code to find 'by' word ad print
for line in teks:
        for part in line.split():
            if "by" in part:
                print (part )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228808/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-tursunwali).